# What does '~=' mean in this line of code?

Tags: sas

My professor has given us some practise exercises to get comfortbale with DATA steps in SAS. One of the exercises we have been given is the following:

```
DATA test;
        SET my_dataset;
        IF my_var =. THEN DO;
                IF my_date ~="."d THEN
                    indicator = 1
                ELSE indicator = 0;
        END;
RUN;
```

What exactly is "~=" doing in this scenario?

I've looked into it in the SAS documentation and couldn't find a concrete example of this.

Comment: If I Google it I immediately find the [documentation here](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/lrcon/9.4/p00iah2thp63bmn1lt20esag14lh.htm) which states it means "not equal"

Comment: I couldn't find `=.` in SAS documentation. Is it a typo?

Comment: Not a typo.   In SAS , `.` indicates a missing value for a numeric value.

Comment: But here the `.` is between quotes followed by "d", so SAS is "asked" to interpret the quoted value as a DATE. The quoted value being a dot, it's interpreted as a null date. So the statement `IF my_date ~="."d THEN` means if my date is not equal to text value "." converted into a SAS date, then...

Answer (score 4):

The standard logical NOT symbol is ¬, which corresponds to EBCDIC code point X'5F' used on IBM mainframes.  That symbol does not exist in ASCII codes.

So when SAS made a version that can run on ASCII computers (like Unix or DOS/Windows) it had to decide what ASCII character could be used in place of the NOT symbol.  They decided to use ~.

So ~= means "not equal".  It is less confusing if you either use the mnemonic NE instead.

```
if my_date ne "."d then ...
```

Or rewrite the expression so you can use the NOT keyword.

```
if not (my_date = "."d) then ...
```

The really strange thing in that code the `"."d`.  The quoted string with the letter D appended indicates a DATE literal.  What goes inside the quotes is anything that the DATE informat can convert into a date value.  So today's date could be written as `"17OCT2023"d` or `'10-oct-2023'D`. The DATE informat will convert a period into a missing value.  So it would simpler and clearer to just write

```
if my_date ne . then ...
```

Or even clearer

```
if not missing(my_date) then ...
```

NOTE: that last one will also exclude special missing values of MY_DATE in addition to the normal missing values.  So if MY_DATE is equal to .A then `MISSING(MY_DATE)` is TRUE but `(MY_DATE=.)` is FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

| Symbol | Mnemonic Equivalent | Definition | Example |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ~= | NE | not equal to |  |

https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000780367.htm

Comment: As show in the doc link `^=` is also *not equal*.  More funnly, the `where` statement, `where=` option and SQL `where` clause will all interpret `<>` as *not equal* and when used in non-where data step statements `<>` is the `MAX` operator.